# Getting name of image placed inside the picturebox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Today my Problem Is that, i m working with large number of images using imagelist control in vb.net 2008, so i want to do that when we displaying any image in picturebox, then the name of this image will be automatically displayed in a textbox or label parallely. I have tried some code but its not working or getting error which i dont understand. This code is..

```
TextBox1.Text = PictureBox2.Image.Tag.ToString
```

[image]

Comment: If you didnt assign something to the Tag it is Nothing and you cant use `.ToString()` on Nothing

Comment: ...you also probably want to assign the filename to the PictureBox.Tag not the image which is transient